# Why does glGenTextures returns zero on OpenGL context Thread (Android)?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es

I'm having a problem where GLES20.glGenTextures() is returning zero for the texture name, even when run on the original thread (which is the OpenGL context thread).

When I run the code

```
final Handler handlerForOriginalThread = new Handler(activity.getMainLooper());

final int[] textureHandleA = new int[1];
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandleA, 0);
Log.v(TAG, "textureHandle (A): " + textureHandleA[0]);

new Thread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        //[Prepare bitmap here]

        handlerForOriginalThread.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];
                GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
                Log.v(TAG, "textureHandle (B): " + textureHandle[0]);

                //[Load bitmap to texture here]
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

glGenTextures returns a valid name for (A) and zero for (B).

Why is this occurring?

This is similar to [glGenTextures returns zero in background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467935/glgentextures-returns-zero-in-background-thread) , but in this case the code is actually running on the OpenGL context thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  It turns out that the "original thread" is not the same as my activity's main looper.

```
long origThreadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
Log.d(TAG, "origThreadID (A): " + origThreadID);
final Handler handlerForOriginalThread = new Handler(activity.getMainLooper());

new Thread(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {

        handlerForOriginalThread.post(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                long origThreadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();
                Log.d(TAG, "origThreadID (B): " + origThreadID);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Results in

```
origThreadID (A): 9467
origThreadID (B): 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I found out that it also returns 0 if either:

1) You call it before calling eglMakeCurrent()
2) You have a mismatch with the surface attributes and then the eglMakeCurrent seems to have worked but actually writes a

> eglMakeCurrent:992 error 3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)

to the log

Comment: This is what I'm experiencing. It took me forever to figure it out. Thanks for confirming